# how to use microsoft authenticator app to approve a request from my asp.net core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, two-factor-authentication, authenticator

Our company have microsoft teams account.

My question is how can i use microsoft authenticator app to approve a request from my asp.net core app?

Is there any api, nuget package or sample code for this purpose?

I want use microsoft authenticator app to approve an action in one of my pages

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean it shall be mandatory to "2-Factor-Approve" the action, each time it is called, regardless of if the user is already authenticated? Like a "are you sure?" - Message-Box just with MS Authenticator?

Comment: dear @Fildor , i use active directory in my app and any body authenticates with microsoft email. i want use ms authenticator to make sure the user is the same user who is authenticated. for example after clicking on a button i send an approve notification on ms authenticator and wait for accept by user

Comment: Does this article useful to you ? [Multi-factor authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @JasonPan I read this document and it did not help me. my main problem is the issue of request approval in ms authenticator app. finally, I designed a simple application for this purpose and my problem was solved. thanks for your comment